# "Таким макаром" - при чем тут Макар?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Вообще, как я замечаю, у русского языка весьма сложные отношения с неким Макаром. Вспомним выражение "куда Макар телят не гонял" в значении "в неизвестность", "куда подальше", "в очень неприятное место" (туда обычно в сердцах посылают). А еще есть выражение "таким макаром" в значении "таком образом", "таким способом", правда, является оно более просторечным.
И вот мне стало интересно, о каком Макаре речь и почему именно это имя вошло в поговорки?

Comment: А я всегда был уверен, что "каким окаром"... и когда слышал "Макаром", всё время думал, что это неграмотно и чё ещё за Макар? И вот сейчас в очередной раз услышал "макара", и решил-таки найти, как правильно.
Ничего про "каким окаром" не находится вообще. У меня жуткий когнитивный диссонанс - я не могу принять выражение "каким макаром", оно мне не нравится, режит слух и выносит мозг. Ужасно, по-моему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Материал по теме можно прочитать здесь: http://elizari7lpe.narod.ru/proishojdenie/proishojdenie_vyrajeniya_quot_takim_makarom_quot.html

ПЕРЕСКАЗ

В Словаре "Фразеологизмы в русской речи" предположение делается такое: выражение восходит к фольклору, где имя "Макар" ассоциируется с бедным, несчастным человеком, крайним неудачником. Ну и в самом деле, вспомните: "На бедного Макара все шишки валятся" или "Не рука Макару калачи есть". В XIX веке "макарами" в народной речи прозывались плуты, а "макарыгами" - попрошайки.

Ну а сочетание "таким макаром" образовалось, очевидно, от выражения "таким образом" с собственным именем "Макар". Это не первое выражение, образованное от личного имени: вспомните словечки "подкузьмить" и "объегорить".

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1)Таким макаром - это "так, таким способом" (прост.) Например:

(2)Таким макаром можно всю ночь протрястись и никаких прудов не найти.

(3)Разве таким макаром фронт снабдишь?

(4)На полпути домой сегодня ночью, дойдя уже до знакомых мест, посмотрел на часы, и прикинул, что таким макаром без двадцати три буду дома.

Не спеши, парень. Момент выбери. Чтоб наверняка — как в аптеке. И глаз не напрягай впустую, для выстрела береги, — бормотал старик. — Вот таким макаром и бей!

КОММЕНАРИЙ

Выражение экспрессивное и, скорее всего, оценочное. Иногда "таким макаром" - это особый, авторский прием, удачный или не очень. В других случаях  это конкретная  ситуация, которой автор дает эмоциональную оценку. Что касается самого Макара, то  не исключено, что в этом выражении он фигурирует то как бедняк неудачник, а то как находчивый плут.

Answer (score 0):

вдобавок к другим вариантам, предлагаю свою гипотезу: из тюркских языков. [мәкер](https://tatar_russian.academic.ru/29783) в татарском языке -     кова́рство, хи́трость, плутовство́, уло́вки, ухищре́ния, вероло́мство. [произношение](https://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BC%D3%99%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80/). [это из арабского макр](http://www.antat.ru/ru/iyli/publishing/book/2015/etimologicheskiy-slovar.php), [مَكْر](http://bars.org.ru/articles?id=32576).

и ещё другая гипотеза: напрямую из арабского.

Comment: qdinar, уведомление просит вас обосновать возможность («может быть») заимствования из тюркских языков. Лично мне еще интересно, что вы имели в виду под «персидскими языками» в предыдущих редакциях ответа...

Comment: @Aer https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @Aer какой аспект этой возможности нужно написать? нужно написать что тюрки соседи русских, а также сейчас все тюрки россии и многие бывшего ссср знают русский язык? или это считается всем тут известным и писать не надо?

Comment: @Aer я не могу сказать что-то определённое о (не)возможности перехода мәкер в макар. но я же не утверждаю что это точно так было, и не утверждаю что это наиболее вероятный вариант. на этом сайте нельзя писать орисс и некие гипотезы?

Comment: qdinar, иранские не равно "персидские", но это ладно. Ну, какое-нибудь обоснование того, как слово могло быть заимствовано, было бы неплохо привести. Прошу прощения, я перепутал уведомления: в том, которое прикреплено к вашему ответу, просят привести ссылки на надежные ресурсы, в которых было бы сказано, что те или иные тюркские слова послужили источником русского Макара. Если вы таких не найдете, наверно, ответ не будет удален, однако уведомление останется.